# Xamarin Forms MessagingCenter after Navigation.PushAsync method does not populate listview

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have two pages lets assume PageA and PageB (PageB has a listview named listview). I want to send a class object to PageB.

```
MessagingCenter.Send<PageA, FooClass>(this, "foo", foo);
await Navigation.PushAsync(new PageB());
```

and PageB s OnAppearing method is like (I used OnAppearing I run async operations in subscribe method )

```
 MessagingCenter.Subscribe<PageA, FooClass>(this, "foo", async (page, source) => {
  listview.ItemSource = ...// Some method
 });
 MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<ProfilesPage>(this, "Company");
```

listview does not populate allthough listview.ItemSource is not empty. but when I change PageA s codes like

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new PageB());           
MessagingCenter.Send<PageA, FooClass>(this, "foo", foo);
```

it works. What is not wrong this?

Comment: I love MessagingCenter, but in this scenario it would be much simple to just pass the data to `PageB` via it's constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course that the first case won't work. What you are doing is:

1. Notify the `MessagingCenter`'s subscriber that the collection has changed;
2. After that you are pushing the new page and subscribing to the topic.

After page B has rendered, the subscription has already been executed, but there was no one to get the message.

The second approach is the correct one, because you first initialise the page (and it subscribes to the topic) and after that, when you have a subscriber already, you are initiating the notify logic.

Basically, in the first case you "shout" your message first and then someone appears that can hear the shouting. But at the time of "shouting" the message, there was no one to hear it.

However, in this particular case you don't need the `MessagingCenter`. The easier and the better approach is to pass the data in the ctor.